# Akon: name of cities of origin and languages spoken at home by his parents

Tags: hip-hop

I was searching Wikipedia for some information about Akon. I wanted to know the name of the exact cities of origin and nationalities of his parents as well as what languages they spoke at home with Akon, besides US English, as well as what languages Akon was exposed to as a child during his travels and what not.

I couldn't find it.

Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

### Cities of Origin

From his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akon).

> - born in St. Louis (MO)
> - [childhood until 7] [Senegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senegal)
> - At 7 ( . . . ) Union City (NJ), splitting his time between the United States and Senegal
> - Settling in Newark (NJ)
> - Highschool ( . . . ) Jersey City.

### His Parents

Mother: [Kine Gueye Thiam](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kine-gueye-thiam-6761909a), a dancer **from Senegal** and president of the Konfidence Foundation.
Father: [Mor Thiam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mor_Thiam), born in **Dakar, Senegal** is a Senegalese drummer, cultural historian and entertainment consultant.

### Spoken Languages

From his [french Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akon):

> Il parle **anglais**, **wolof** et un peu le **français**, qu'il a fini par oublier quand il est arrivé aux États-Unis.
>
> He speaks **english**, [**wolof**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolof_language) and a little **french** he ended losing when he arrived in the US.

- English: main language spoken in the US.
- Wolof: african language partially spoken in Senegal.
- French: official language of Senegal.